# how to implement a base model for all models in play using ebean?

Tags: playframework, ebean

I am trying to implement a base model for all models in my project, the base class looks like following:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseModel extends Model {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1658731911988408622L;

    @CreatedTimestamp
    public Date createdAt;
    public Date updatedAt;

    protected final void doBeforeSave() {
        Date now = new Date();
        createdAt = updatedAt = now;
        beforeSave();
    }

    protected void beforeSave() {
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save() {
        doBeforeSave();
        super.save();
    }
}
```

Here is the subclass extends the above BaseModel and the client code to save an order to db:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order extends BaseModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -97840064118194854L;

    @Id
    @Constraints.Min(10)
    public Long id;
}

// save an order
Order order = new Order();
order.save()
```

I am getting the following exception when 'order.save' is executed.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: models.Order._ebean_getni_updatedAt()Ljava/util/Date;
    at models.Order._ebean_getField(Order.java:1)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.reflect.EnhanceBeanReflect$Getter.get(EnhanceBeanReflect.java:162)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanProperty.getValue(BeanProperty.java:756)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dmlbind.BindableProperty.dmlBind(BindableProperty.java:78)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dmlbind.BindableProperty.dmlBind(BindableProperty.java:63)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dmlbind.BindableList.dmlBind(BindableList.java:56)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.InsertMeta.bind(InsertMeta.java:145)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.InsertHandler.bind(InsertHandler.java:110)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:79)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.insert(DmlBeanPersister.java:57)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersistExecute.executeInsertBean(DefaultPersistExecute.java:66)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNow(PersistRequestBean.java:448)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeOrQueue(PersistRequestBean.java:478)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:331)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveEnhanced(DefaultPersister.java:306)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveRecurse(DefaultPersister.java:276)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.save(DefaultPersister.java:244)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1610)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1600)
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.save(Ebean.java:453)
    at play.db.ebean.Model.save(Model.java:95)
    at core.BaseModel.save(BaseModel.java:69)
    at controllers.Orders.index(Orders.java:19)
```

**Order** implements **BaseModel**, it should have *updatedAt* field, but *order.save* failed any way!